# Not able to set memory limit on containers in docker

Tags: linux, docker

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with latest docker.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
```

`3.18.5-x86_64-linode52` kernel

But when i try to set the memory

```
-m="512m" 
-c=512
```

Then i get this error

```
WARNING: Your kernel does not support memory limit capabilities. Limitation discarded.
```

Comment: you need to be sure your host has cgroup subsystem in working state, i'm using ubuntu 14.10 and cgroup is configured by default

Comment: @c4f4t0r  I have server on linode , how can i check what your r saying

Comment: You might need to check this `https://gist.github.com/rfc1459/87b8e2d9f35075ce0a98`

Comment: @PratapSingh is it ok to do it on live production server

Comment: I would suggest to check on test machine then try it on production ..in case you do not have test/stage machine then please take a backup of files/folders you are editing as per the url and restore it in case of any issue. You can apply as well on production.

Comment: @PratapSingh i tried that and reboot system but still get same error

Answer (score 2):

Pass `cgroup_enable=memory` to `grub`. Preferred way is to create a file in `/etc/default/grub.d`:

```
cat > /etc/default/grub.d/memory.cfg <<EOF
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX cgroup_enable=memory"
EOF
```

- run `update-grub2`
- `reboot`

After reboot `cgroups` should be mounted under `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/`.

Answer (score 1):

Run sudoedit /etc/default/grub in a terminal and edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Save and exit and then run sudo update-grub and reboot. That should be enough.

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/417215/how-does-kernel-support-swap-limit